# Postgresql a strange tsquery behavior

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

```
select  to_tsvector('english', 'Ice-cream') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'Ice<->cream');
```

is True. While:

```
select  to_tsvector('english', 'iDream  Ice-cream  iScream') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'iDream<->Ice<->cream<->iScream');
```

is False.

For my understand. Both add same word before and after the match one. It will keep the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because full-text search treats hyphenated words specially:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'iDream  Ice cream  iScream');

               to_tsvector                
------------------------------------------
 'cream':3 'ice':2 'idream':1 'iscream':4
(1 row)
```

The numbers behind the lexemes mark the position they had in the original text (`cream` is the third word, and so on). That is used for phrase search.

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'iDream  Ice-cream  iScream');

                      to_tsvector                       
--------------------------------------------------------
 'cream':4 'ice':3 'ice-cream':2 'idream':1 'iscream':5
(1 row)
```

You see that the original hyphenated word is at the second position, and the parts are represented as following the hyphenated word.

So `ice cream` is *not* the same as `ice-cream` for PostgreSQL full text search.
In the first case, `ice` immediately follows `idream`, but not in the second case. That is why your query returns `FALSE`.

Look at what the parser does:

```
SELECT alias, token, lexemes FROM ts_debug('english', 'iDream  Ice-cream  iScream');

      alias      |   token   |   lexemes   
-----------------+-----------+-------------
 asciiword       | iDream    | {idream}
 blank           |           | 
 asciihword      | Ice-cream | {ice-cream}
 hword_asciipart | Ice       | {ice}
 blank           | -         | 
 hword_asciipart | cream     | {cream}
 blank           |           | 
 asciiword       | iScream   | {iscream}
(8 rows)
```

Perhaps the solution you are looking for would be to ignore hyphenated words and just keep their parts:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION en_no_hyphen
   (COPY = english);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION en_no_hyphen
   DROP MAPPING FOR asciihword, hword;

SELECT to_tsvector('en_no_hyphen', 'iDream  Ice-cream  iScream')
       @@ to_tsquery('en_no_hyphen', 'iDream<->Ice<->cream<->iScream');

 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi . can you have a look about https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271419/how-postgresql-to-tsvector-translate-u-s-to-u-and-s-not-u-s . How to disable `file alias` but only acciiword?