# Why tsquery containing a hyphen isn't found in full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Trying to figure out, why the below query isn't returning any results:

```
select id from story where tsv_story_text @@ to_tsquery('CumEx-Files<->2.0');
```

The term exists in the headline of a story in the database (PostgreSQL 11.12) like:

```
CumEx-Files 2.0 investigation reveals €150bn tax fraud
```

The only way I could get the query to work was to replace the hyphen with a dash in both the vector and the query **which worked**, so I tried debugging the phrase, but it seems like the hyphen is but a space symbol - I thought it has to do something with the numerals in the phrase, or is it?

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english', 'CumEx-Files<->2.0');
      alias      |           description           |    token    |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  |   lexemes
-----------------+---------------------------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------
 asciihword      | Hyphenated word, all ASCII      | CumEx-Files | {english_stem} | english_stem | {cumex-fil}
 hword_asciipart | Hyphenated word part, all ASCII | CumEx       | {english_stem} | english_stem | {cumex}
 blank           | Space symbols                   | -           | {}             |              |
 hword_asciipart | Hyphenated word part, all ASCII | Files       | {english_stem} | english_stem | {file}
 blank           | Space symbols                   | <           | {}             |              |
 blank           | Space symbols                   | ->          | {}             |              |
 float           | Decimal notation                | 2.0         | {simple}       | simple       | {2.0}
```

Comment: It works for me: `SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'CumEx-Files 2.0 investigation reveals €150bn tax fraud') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'CumEx-Files<->2.0');` gives me "true".

Comment: this is weird, pasted the above query into my terminal and I get `false` for `?column?`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, what version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: I guess this is a [duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271074/179952) of an issue you already answered where hyphenated are the issue. Wondering, if the solution is to create a new configuration where you disable hyphens, why isn't  that a default, and one in need, would turn it on - however I don't understand when would hyphens accepted if it renders your searches to false?

Comment: I am using 14.1, but that behavior hasn't changed, as far as I know. Could it be that you have different, but similar looking character than `-` somewhere in there?

Comment: This will drive me crazy, unfortunately no, its all the same. As said, pasted your snippet into my terminal as is and it returns false right away. Tried casting and decomposing the string, tsvector: `'2.0':4 'cumex':2 'cumex-fil':1 'file':3 'fraud':9 'investig':5 'reveal':6 'tax':8 '€150bn':7`, tsqeury: `( 'cumex-fil' & 'cumex' & 'file' ) <-> '2.0` - it seems fine to me, but it still returns false when compared :(

Comment: Noticed that `phraseto_tsquery()` - works instead of `to_tsquery()`, which ties all tokens via `<->`. Mimicked this behaviour and I manage to get a match for my hyphenated queries. I'm wondering, how was this working for you?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: `I am using 14.1, but that behavior hasn't changed, as far as I know.` It has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was change of behavior in Postgres 14. (A fix, really, but not back-patched, because change of behavior ...)

The [release notes for Postgres 14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-14.html):

- Fix [**`to_tsquery()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) and `websearch_to_tsquery()` to properly parse query text containing discarded tokens (Alexander Korotkov)

  Certain discarded tokens, like underscore, caused the output of these functions to produce incorrect tsquery output, e.g., both `websearch_to_tsquery('"pg_class pg"')` and `to_tsquery('pg_class <-> pg')` used to output `( 'pg' & 'class' ) <-> 'pg'`, but now both output `'pg' <-> 'class' <-> 'pg'`.

That's ***exactly*** what happens in your case. Compare the results in the following two fiddles:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6f4d0e94a5fd13801b380565544bf85b)* - **Postgres 11**

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6f4d0e94a5fd13801b380565544bf85b)* - **Postgres 14**

So your query:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'CumEx-Files 2.0 investigation reveals €150bn tax fraud') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'CumEx-Files<->2.0');
```

... now works as expected in Postgres 14 or later (returns `true`). Consider upgrading.